# How to completly disable menu button on android?

Tags: android, android-button, android-menu

For some reason if i long press my menu button while my app is loading content, it is just stops just like i pressed back key.

I dont want the menu button to behave like this so my question is:

How can i completly disable menu button ? I dont ever need it in my app i just want to turn it off.

i tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        onBackPressed();
     }


    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
        return true;
    } 
    else{
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }

}
```

Menu button still working...

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: if you use ProgressDialog to download data then set ProgressDialog cancelable true. then you do not need to disable back-menu.

Comment: In some of the samsung phones long press menu is mapped to search. If your phone is samsung, return true for Search key

Comment: Nothing works yet, if i press long the menu button, my progress dialog got cancelled, and my app crashes. I really need a way to kill this stupid menu button i dont need it why i cant just turn it off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.
So I'm guessing this will work:

```
@Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
     .... .....
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: If I only want to 'disable' it, not hide it, then?

Comment: From API-11, this method has been changed.
`public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)`

Comment: This method doesn't work well when subclassing AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 3):

You must return **false**.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(final int featureId, final Menu menu) {
    super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried all the onKeyDown/onKeyUp/dispatchTouchEvent/onPreparedOptionsMenu methods. this is the only one that worked for me

Comment: Works with AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

I've had to disable the menu button as well, what I did was add the following line:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
   return true;
}
```

Which basically tells the OS that all buttons pressed where already dealt with, so no action is to be taken. Add it after the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
     return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ? true : super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one you have posted should work,
still try this, it should work

```
@Override  
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {  
     final int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();  
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
         return true;
     } 

     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

Comment: with your code i get error variable keyCode is already defined.